# I've got the answer to my probability question, but don't understand why?

Tags: probability

The question is this:
According to a sample of 200 samples of ground meat:

P(One of the Samples was contaminated with Salmonella) = 0.15

P(Salmonella-contaminated sample was contaminated by a strain resistant to at least 1 antibiotic) = 0.77

P(Salmonella-contaminated sample was contaminated by a strain resistant to at least 3 antibiotics) = 0.53

Find the probability that a ground meat that was contaminated by an antibiotic-resistant strain was contaminated by a strain resistant to at least 3 antibiotics. (Round to 3 d.p)

What I did was divide 0.53 by 0.77, to get the rounded answer 0.688 (which was incidentally right), and I'm unsure as to whether this is conditional probability or not, because dividing those two to get the answer was a fluke, and I would like to understand why the answer is what I got.

I'm assuming that the 3rd event (Salmonella-contaminated) somehow cancels when you divide those 2 probabilities, but I don't understand which rule is applied, or if there's actually a series of assumptions we make when we do divide those two probabilities.

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps out.

Answer (score 4):

Let $S$ represent the event that a sample was contaminated with *Salmonella*, and $R$ represent a random variable that counts the number of antibiotics to which the sample was resistant, **given** that $S$ occurred.  Then we can write more compactly $$\Pr[R \ge 1] = 0.77, \quad \Pr[R \ge 3] = 0.53.$$  We want $$\Pr[R \ge 3 \mid R \ge 1] = \frac{\Pr[R \ge 1 \mid R \ge 3]\Pr[R \ge 3]}{\Pr[R \ge 1]}.$$  Note all probabilities are conditional upon the presence of *Salmonella*, because we are assuming that in all cases the sample is contaminated.  But since $R \ge 3$ implies $R \ge 1$, $$\Pr[R \ge 1 \mid R \ge 3] = 1,$$ because the event $R \ge 3$ is a subset of the event $R \ge 1 $.  Therefore, the desired probability simplifies to $$\frac{\Pr[R \ge 3]}{\Pr[R \ge 1]},$$ which is what you computed.  Were it not the case that the events of interest were nested, you would need to adjust the computation accordingly.